# Can't figure out a KISS way to setup a IDP so that I can develop a SAML SP

Tags: saml-2.0

I'm new to SAML.  New in a "Ohh my god, there are so many things! My brain hurts." kind of way.

I get the basic idea. A IDP logs in the user, and sends the SP notification said person has logged in so the SP can log them in too. There is a whole bunch of hand shaking involved on both sides.

The problem is, I don't know nearly enough about SAML (and I'm struggling to figure it all out) to just get something simple setup. So far I figure if I can get a simple IDP going I can then work on the SP after. Play around with it. Get to know it.

So I've been trying to set one up with OneLogin, and I have created an application. But the sheer number of settings is overload to me and online documentation/guides seem to assume I understand what needs to be put where. I have little clue except for MAYBE the EntityID.

Can someone help me?  Even if it's a nice video, or some other site I haven't been able to find. This is one of the most overwhelming projects I've ever been assigned and I'm starting to feel defeated.

If there is anything I can clarify, let me know.

Comment: Q: So what exactly is your "assignment"?  Are there any specific requirements?  You need to focus on *specific objectives*, then work backwards from there.

Comment: The requirements are very broad. We have companies that want to log into our service from their login page.  Most likely we want to link the accounts via email, but that isn't set in stone yet.

Comment: It sounds like your management needs to decide on a "pilot project".  Tell your management that without some good, explicit requirements: this project (*ANY* project) is almost certainly doomed to flounder ... and then fail.  Q: Are you already committed to [OneLogin](https://www.onelogin.com/)?  Or are you willing to explore alternatives?  Q: If you're committed to OneLogin - can management arrange for OneLogin training for you?

Comment: If there is a simplier site than OneLogin (I was using it mainly because the library's demo I'm working with, uses it in thier sample IDP data) I can certainly try it. The problem is we are a start up company. Only a couple years old. Hard for the management to set requirements when they have no idea what they are (and trust me, it is a source of much frustration).

Comment: https://capriza.github.io/samling/samling.html is a really easy way of testing SAML

Comment: The bare minimum you likely need from a SP side is: entity ID/audience (shared secret), the cert from the IDP, and the URL of the IdP for login for your app.  The IdP will generally need the URL to redirect to after processing a request (where it sends the SAMLResponse) and the entityID/audience

Comment: Q: Do you even need/want SAML???  Your company needs to get a clue before you commit to any serious decisions.  STRONG SUGGESTION: "Pilot projects", "Proof of Concept" projects - whatever you want to call them - are ESSENTIAL to giving you tne information you need to make informed, intelligent decisions.  STRONG SUGGESTION: Consider the alternatives in these articles, then decide how best to proceed: https://www.okta.com/identity-101/whats-the-difference-between-oauth-openid-connect-and-saml/, https://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/an-updated-look-at-choosing-between-oauth2-and-saml/.

Comment: ALSO: SAML is often used primarily for "SSO".  Perhaps all you want is "Authentication".  Perhaps OAuth2 might be the better technology to focus on?  https://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/choosing-an-sso-strategy-saml-vs-oauth2/

Comment: I will try setting something up with that Samling site. We do need SAML, as far as I know at least.  The company that is going to use our product, uses SAML and if a company asks for something my boss (the owner of the company) will bend over backwards to provide it.  I can't say it's smart buisness, but egh. What do I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with most of the comments.

You want to develop a SAML SP. That assumes that you or your company has a SAML IDP in mind. Which one?

Each IDP is slightly different but for all the IDP e.g. Azure AD, Auth0, Okta, OneLogin etc. they all have step by step tutorials. They also have YouTube videos you can follow.

There is a list [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-idp-to-test-now-477761595b60) of potential IDP with instructions.

The key is to decide which IDP and then we can advise further.

Comment: Our IDP is what ever the company we are working with uses. My bosses refuses to let me talk to them about it, until we have a working prototype to show them.

Comment: I asked again and he has told me Active Directory. So I at least have something.

Comment: I have found another stopping point. I've looked into sites like Azure AD and OneLogin to setup IDP, but they all seam to want me to select an app. I have no idea which app I should select if any of them. Probably another thing I would ask the companies we are working with about if I could.

Comment: I assume that means Active Directory Federation Services? I would use ComponentSpace. It's free for a month if I remember and it comes with samples for all the major IDP including ADFS. It also includes an IDP. So you can run up a SAML SP to a SAML IDP with minimal effort and you can show your boss that. In Firefox you can use SAML Tracer to see the traffic. There's a similar one for Chrome as well. They both decode the SAML for you.

Comment: Just to answer your other question, In Azure AD, you configure an Enterprise application. This is not the app per se. You then build your app. using a client-side SAML stack. Refer https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43